# main() function in bison file not running

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

So I'm trying to make a compiler using flex, bison and C. In my step3.y file, I have this main function:

step3.y

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filename[100];
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    if (argc == 2) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        printf("filename is %s\n", filename);
    }
    else {
        printf("No files - Exit\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    yyparse();
    printf("\nMain symbol table");
    Display();
    printf("the input has been syntactically checked\n");
    printf("starting print\n*\n*\n*\n*\n*\n");
    ASTprint(0, prog);
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm running these commands in my cygwin:

```
bison -d step3.y
flex step3.fl
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl -o step3
```

Previously I tried using

```
gcc step3.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -o step3
```

but that caused a lot of errors of "Multiple definitions of 'said function'" so I removed that and now it compiles without errors.

Anyways, when executing those 3 commands, I get no output. Not even a printf.

In my step3.fl file I have the following option included:

```
%option noyywrap
```

Why isn't my function main() not running? How can I make it run?

Comment: @GeorgiHristozov flex and lex are different tools. The correct tag for flex, the lexical analyzer, is flex-lexer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your main isn't running when you compile using `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl -o step3` is pretty simple: You're not compiling the yacc-generated code at all. So not only is your `main` not part of the final executable, none of your parser code is. The generated executable contains your lexer only.

So why do you get an error about multiple definitions when you try to include the parser code? Apparently because your parser and lexer define functions with the same names. Just like with any other C project, the same function should not be defined in more than one compilation unit, so you should define your functions only once and then only declare them in the other compilation units (that's what header files are usually used for).

Comment: Well, if I remove the -lfl flag, and only do this:
gcc step3.tab.c lex.yy.c -o step3 
I get multiple definitions error

Comment: @PiguFilms Still "multiple definitions of *main*" or something else?

Comment: I've never had "multiple definitions of main". I've always had "Multiple definitions of 'insert function here'" http://i.piju.me/eI10527.png
Those are all functions that are located in 2 other files. One for AST and other for symbol table.

Comment: @PiguFilms You could have mentioned that (also I'm pretty sure you did get one for `main` as well when linking with `-lfl` - you probably just didn't see it among all the others). Anyway, that problem is clearly unrelated to the code in your question and you should ask a separate question about that (which I now remember already having told you on another question of yours).

Comment: @sepp2k: if `main` is in an object file, any definition in a library is not used; no errors result. You can use `-lfl` just fine with an explicit `main`. There's little point, since `%option noyywrap` makes `-lfl` irrelevant, but it shouldn't produce any errors

Comment: @rici That's interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @sepp2k Yeah, you did in another question of mine! Thanks though, I'll create another question for the errors above.